# How to use weka ClassifierSubsetEval

Tags: attributes, machine-learning, selection, weka, genetic-algorithm

I am using weka on a dataset with ~9000 attributes. I want to run an attribute selection on the dataset and tried the ClassifierSubsetEval AttributeSelection filter. I varied the used Classifiers and search methods. 
I am not a machine learner per se, so I do a lot with trial and error.

What I am wondering about:

When I use ClassifierSubsetEval for example with NaiveBayes in combination with GeneticSearch in standard settings, get a selection of about 3000 attributes. However if I use the same classifier with BestFirst forward (standard settings as well as increased number of nonimproving nodes up to 100) I always gett about 25 attributes.

1) Why is the difference so huge? Is the AttributeSelection with BestFirst not getting away from a local optimum?

2) How can I set the GeneticSearch more strict? 3000 attributes seems still a lot.

3) Are there any Classifiers that work especially well with specific search methods? I often see NaiveBayes mentioned together with GeneticSearch.

4) In which cases is it better to use WrapperSubsetEval and why?

Thanks to anyone willing to help or showing me where to look for answers!

Comment: Haven't used Weka for a while now, but I can help with a bit of your questions. (3) Naive bayes is often used with genetic search because it is very quick learning method (relatively) and incremental by nature. Genetic search repeatidly learn the problem, so naive search is pretty efficient for it.

Comment: Also, try using PCA. In PCA - you can pretty much control how much features you are going to take by selecting the `X` first columns of the generated PCA matrix. Downside: Each feature is a combination of the old features, so it might be meaningless at times, which could be a problem

Comment: Another option, when using a large dimensionality problem (and I mean even for 10,000 scale) - SVM handles it very good without the need to use subset selection, it does it for you. You can even later use the resulting hyperplane to select subset of the feature by taking those with the highest weight (absolute value), and ignoring those we weight close to 0.

Comment: @amit Thanks a lot for the comments, I will certainly try your suggestions! By SVM, do you mean the ClassifierSubsetEval filter together with SVM, SVM as classifier on its own or the SVMAttributeEval AttributeSelection?

Comment: I mean SVM as its own, use it to create the seperating hyperplane and it handles how much weight to give to each feature on its own (at least from my experience)